# Regional Formats, create my own, covering ALL, how?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, language, locale

Is there a single easy option to have an "International" Region/Language option?

e.g. I wish to have a DATE format as indicated by these...

```
$ date --rfc-3339=date
2022-10-10

$ date --iso-8601=date
2022-10-10

$ date --rfc-3339=seconds
2022-10-10 16:22:55+02:00

$ date --iso-8601=seconds
2022-10-10T16:23:06+02:00

$
```

Time should ALWAYS be "24h", skip that pesky AM/PM.

Numbers; decimal POINT, and possibly space as thousands separator.

Ref:
[How do I enter dates in ISO 8601 date format (YYYY-MM-DD) in Excel (and have Excel recognize that format as a date value)?](https://superuser.com/questions/409896/how-do-i-enter-dates-in-iso-8601-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-in-excel-and-have-exc)
[How to make date YYYY-MM-DD (ISO-8601) the default in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/989370/how-to-make-date-yyyy-mm-dd-iso-8601-the-default-in-excel)
... and probably more, similar.

Comment: It looks that there are missing tags, probably  related to the operative system (Windows maybe) and the application (Excel, LibreOffice, not sure that this applies to Word, Power Point etc.)

Answer (score 1):

---

---

> The name of your locale has to be stated in either
> /etc/locale.gen
> -or-
> /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED

---

---

In the end, the number grouping symbol actually already was set to Narrow-Non-Break-Space `<U+202F>`, didn't have to change that (I have seen `,` in use at some point, can't remember when).

The use of `,` (comma) as decimal marker was present though, both in monetary and general number format specifications; I replaced that with the more "versatile" `.` (period). So, the sequence of commands... and use of the nano editor for the changes:

```
$ cp /usr/share/i18n/locales/sv_SE sv_SE_nerdy

$ nano sv_SE_nerdy 

$ diff -bu0 /usr/share/i18n/locales/sv_SE sv_SE_nerdy 
--- /usr/share/i18n/locales/sv_SE   2022-04-07 03:24:41.000000000 +0200
+++ sv_SE_nerdy 2022-10-21 22:22:00.321168816 +0200
@@ -182 +182 @@
-mon_decimal_point       ","
+mon_decimal_point       "."
@@ -198 +198 @@
-decimal_point           ","
+decimal_point           "."
@@ -276 +276 @@
-lang_name    "svenska"
+lang_name    "svenska, decimalpunkt"

$ sudo cp sv_SE_nerdy /usr/share/i18n/locales/

$ sudo locale-gen

$ localectl set-locale LC_MONETARY=sv_SE_nerdy

$ localectl set-locale LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE_nerdy
```

*NOTED FAULT: The monetary format (as specified above) is not used in LibreOffice Calc 6.4.7.2, or is it just dependent on selecting it? Using English as Language during testing.*